# Bash array transformation like .map() in JavaScript

Tags: bash

In JavaScript, the Array.map() function exists such that

```
const array1 = [1, 4, 9, 16];
const map1 = array1.map(x => x * 2);
console.log(map1);
// expected output: Array [2, 8, 18, 32]
```

I need a bash equivalent where I can take my array, manipulate its contents, then receive a new array with the manipulations.

```
array1=(1 4 9 16)
map1=# ????
echo ${map1[*]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Soooooooo, just write the loop.

```
array1=(1 4 9 16)
map1=()
for i in "${array1[@]}"; do
   map1+=("$((i * 2))")
done
echo "${map1[@]}"
```

I recommend re-reading a good Bash array introduction.

> This code is very procedural and not at all like map

Bash is a shell. A shell is just that, a shell. It is meant for running *other* programs, not run by itself, but Bash comes with an abundance of features. You can first output the numbers of each line and run `awk` in a pipeline to output the numbers, then use `paste` to join the lines:

```
array1=(1 4 9 16)
printf "%s\n" "${array1[@]}" | awk '{print $1 * 2}' | paste -sd ' '
```

Comment: I was hoping there would be a more functional solution. This code is very procedural and not at all like `map`

Comment: @Berry welcome to `bash`. :(

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to implement an `array_walk` with a callback to perform operation on each element this way:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Applies the user-defined callback function to each element of the array. 
#
# @params
# $1: The array name to walk
# $2: The callback command or function name
array_walk() {
  local -n __array=$1
  local -- __callback=$2 __i
  for __i in "${!__array[@]}"; do
    "$__callback" "$1[$__i]"
  done
}

x2() {
  local -n __e=$1
  __e=$((2 * __e))
}

array1=(1 4 9 16)

array_walk array1 x2

printf '%s\n' "${array1[*]}"
```